# POST Content-Length exceeds the limit Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I get this error when I try to upload a theme to Wordpress. It's localhost server and I use XAMPP control panel. I have done the following but it's still not working:

1. Created a *info.php* file in *wp-admin* folder but can't access **localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/info.php** (it says page not found).
2. Found the *php.ini* file in **C:/Program Files/IIS Express/PHP/v7.0** and edited the *post_max_size* and *upload_max_filesize* to 1000M but it doesn't work.

The theme file is only 28 MBs, so I thought a 1000M post_max_size and upload_max_filesize would do.

Please help me with this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. Generally, XAMPP files are not located in the IIS folder (they're more likely in `C:\xampp\` somewhere). The 'A' in XAMPP stands for apache, and IIS is a different/competing web server.

The easiest way to check your upload limit (and PHP ini file location) is to create a new file in your web root with the following contents:

`<?php
phpinfo();`

If you navigate to that, does it have the upload limit you've specified?
(Make sure you remove the file after you're done checking)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There was a php.ini file in C:\xampp\php I changed the size but it's still not working.


I tried creating a file in wp-admin folder called info.php in which I wrote the codes


`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

I can't navigate to that page on my browser, It says page not found.

Comment: Make sure you also restart the web server. Changes won't apply until that happens. Also, what does the `phpinfo()` script say? It should show you what PHP file is being used.

Comment: Try putting the phpinfo script outside of any wordpress folders (ie. Just in the document root - usually `C:\xampp\htdocs`). Does the XAMPP control panel definitely say that Apache is running?

Comment: I created an _info.php_ in C:\xampp\htdocs and it works now.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. That file should show you your PHP ini file being used, as well as your upload limit. Edit the `ini` file that it says it's using, then restart Apache, and your upload limit should take effect.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.